# How to create collections dynamically in mongodb with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have huge record to store for each company, one company can contain 200k records. how can we create a dynamic collection for each company with company name to avoid filtration in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://******";
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const dbname='******';
client.connect(err => {
  const db=client.db(dbname);
  const promises = ['Company1','Company2','Company3'].map(name => db.createCollection(name))
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      client.close()
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

I suggest promise,async,etc.. But if you don't use it,
this would create the collections:

```
client.connect(err => {
  const db=client.db(dbname);
  const companies = ['Company1','Company2','Company3']
  companies.forEach(name=>{
    db.createCollection(name)
  })
})
```

Comment: Is there any other way? I am not using promise

Comment: I have edited. You can do same thing in a loop but it is unable to ensure from the result.